# User Input + Ruby + Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to give users a text area where they can enter text. Later I will match that input against a different input and extract it if matched.

Flow:

- User enters text with returns into a text area
- Text is saved in the db in a text field

Then I use the following to extract:

```
text_reply = text_reply.sub(/#{user.text_to_extract}/m, '').strip
```

Problem is that it appears that characters like new lines or pipes | are breaking it. As input that we want to match against can look like this:

```
XXXXXX

XXXXXX
XXXX & XXXXX
asdasd: 123312321 | dasasddsadasads

http://yahoo.com
```

Suggestions? Thansk

Comment: A simple string replace won't do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to escape the input:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html

See the method `escape`.

```
 Regexp.escape(your_input)
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I escape when I do inputtext.split(regex_to_use).first ?

Comment: You do the same thing to that regex if you are taking in user/string input for the regex.  Use Regex.escape for any string that may have regex special characters that you do not want to be interpreted as so by the regex engine.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. It appears to be a | pipe in the input that break s it.

Comment: Yes which is exactly what escaping it avoids.  A pipe is a special character in regexes

Comment: @AnApprentice: Since you discovered the error here, you can select this as the correct answer and close out this question.