# ruby, given a regex with a pipe | the regex is stopping there. How to safely deal with pipes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app where a user can input text in a textarea. I then use that to match against a large block of text to extract whatever the user entered in the textarea if found.

Problem is, if that textarea includes a | pipe, the it stops at the pipe:

Example:

```
User Input: This is my entry, I should all be remove | thank you very kindly

Larger block of text: blah blah blah blah blah This is my entry, I should all be remove | thank you very kindly

Desired return is: blah blah blah blah blah
```

But what I get back is:

```
bad: blah blah blah blah blah | thank you very kindly
```

The regex works like so:

```
desired = larger_block_of_text.sub(/#{user_input}/m, '').strip
```

Ideas? Thank you

Comment: Do you need it to be a RegExp?

Comment: The sign on the side of the road you just passed said "You're now entering the world of being hacked." The problem with allowing a user to enter text is someone will enter something pathological and, unless you are sufficiently paranoid in your code, it will break your app. This is the basis of SQL Injection attacks. You have to cleanse inputs, escape characters needing escaping, and, in the case of database searches, use parameters instead of interpolating the user's input directly into a SQL statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [User Input + Ruby + Regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396157/user-input-ruby-regex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Regexp.quote(user_input)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001223) to escape the special characters in the regular expression so that they are treated literally.

Note: If you just want to find a constant string you don't need regular expressions. You can instead use a String instead of a regular expression as the argument to `sub`.

```
desired = larger_block_of_text.sub(user_input, '').strip
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call [Regexp.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001224), which will escape all characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

The main reason why you code is stopping after the `|`, is because you are interpolating that string(which contains a special character) into a regex. Just like inserting user data in SQL databases, eval() etc... you have to escape the user input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `user_input` - since the pipe character means something special in a regex, your regex is not doing what you think it should be doing.  Try this:

```
desired = larger_block_of_text.sub(/#{Regexp.quote(user_input)}/m, '').strip
```

Comment: Thanks Brett. Is that Regex, as is fine for this use case?

Comment: You haven't really given a lot of specifics on how your code internally works, but if you have access to the string the user entered (`user_input`) and you just want to remove those characters from `larger_block_of_text`, I would go with Mark Byers' suggestion and avoid using a Regex period.  Straight string comparisons are faster anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

The pipe is interpreted as the alternative operator in regex.