# Make a string a literal regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have an unknown input string, and I want to use it as a regex, but it can have many characters such as (,/,\

In Ruby, Is it possible to specify that the input argument to match is just a literal string.

e.g text.match_literal(string) instead of text.match(string) ?

Or, is the only way to do this by writing a function to backslash the problems?

Thankyou,

Comment: possible duplicate of [User Input + Ruby + Regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396157/user-input-ruby-regex)

Comment: Basically you have to use `Regex.escape(your_input)`, for details see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396157/user-input-ruby-regex)

Comment: Thankyou, that question solves this one.

Comment: `Regexp.escape` ( not `Regex` ) worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index` method:

```
text.index(string)
```