# How to search for regex and replace the characters from string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

Let's say I have a string:

```
asd;;%$@#!G'{}[]
```

Now I want to escape special symbols:

```
;&|><*?`$(){}[]!#
```

So, the output will be something like:

```
asd\;\;%\$@\#\!G\'\{\}\[\]
```

How can I achieve this using `gsub/sub` in Ruby?

Comment: This is the regex for finding out special characters in a string.  
/[;\&\|><\*\?`'\$\(\){}\[\]\!\#]/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5396495/1315563

Answer (score 1):

```
test_value = "asd;;%$@#!G'{}[]"
SPEC_REGEXP = /((;)|(\&)|(\|)|(>)|(<)|(\*)(\?)|(`)|(\$)|(\()|(\))|({)|(})|(\[)|(\])|(!)|(#))/
test_value.gsub!(SPEC_REGEXP,'\\\\\1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's pretty much the same idea as in soundar's solution (but using character classes and no capturing):

```
"asd;;%$@#!G'{}[]".gsub(/[;&|><*?`$(){}\[\]!#]/, '\\\\\\0')
```